# Hidden Markov Model - understanding Viterbi algorithm

Tags: probability, hidden-markov-models

I try to understand the Viterbi algorithm for solving hidden Markov models. There is a pseudo-code of it in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm):

[image]

In the row that marked in blue (starts with $T_2$) I don't understand: how does it choose a state in case where there is more than one state with the maximum likelihood? in this implementation it will pick the first state that has the maximum, but it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it will pick the first state that has the maximum, but it makes no sense

Why not? Ties are esentially irrelevant, in the sense that any election will find the same global maximum. Hence to pick the first one is as correct as picking any other.

Comment: Yes, but in the next step you may get as result that one of these options in the tie is better, so how does the algorithm finds it?

Comment: > in the next step you may get as result that one of these options in the tie is better

No, you won't. That's the point of Viterbi's algorithm.

Comment: O, of course it cannot be, because of the Markov property... Thanks!